# ScalaFiddle divide by zero

Tags: scala

In [this](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/QHrybLv/1) ScalaFiddle, the result of 1/0 is 0. However, the result of 1.0/0 is `Infinity`. Is this a Scala bug or a ScalaFiddle bug, or something else I'm missing?

Comment: `1/0` and `1.0/0` are different things

Comment: @SamDufel I realize that, but my question is about why 1 / 0 = 0 in the referenced ScalaFiddle, instead of an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the behavior of (integer) division by zero in Scala.js.

See:

- https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/160
- https://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html#undefined-behaviors